# How to extension HalfOpenInterval with reduce method

Tags: swift, reduce

I hope to extension `HalfOpenInterval` with `reduce` method
so can easy use some quick code snippet
for example:

```
var a = [3,4,9,7]
var mini = (0..<a.count).reduce(0, combine: { a[$0] > a[$1] ? $0 : $1 })
```

I notice that `HalfOpenInterval` fit `IntervalType` protocol, but not sure how to iterative each element in `reduce` function

```
extension HalfOpenInterval {
    func reduce<T>(initialize: T, combine: (u: U, t:T) -> U) -> U {
        ...
    }
}
```

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, what you should extend is `Range`:

```
extension Range {
    func reduce<U>(initial:U, combine:(U, T) -> U) -> U {
        return Swift.reduce(self, initial, combine)
    }
}

let sum = (0 ..< 12).reduce(0, combine: { $0 + $1}) // -> 66
```

---

`HalfOpenInterval` or `ClosedInterval` is not for that, because it has only "start" and "end" values, but does not have "stride" of each values.  Something like this:

> [image: Inteval]

`Range` also has "start" and "end", and these values itself know the next value of them:

> [image: Range]

Another similar structure, `StrideTo` and `StrideThrough` which constructed with `stride(from:to:by:)` or `stride(from:through:by)`. It also has "start" and "end", and in this case, structure itself knows the "stride" between values.

> [image: Stride]

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `Range` class in the following way.

```
extension Range {

    func reduce<U>(initialize: U, combine: (u: U, t:T) -> U) -> U {

        var result = initialize

        for value in self {
            result = combine(u: result,t: value)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```